# Parse: limitations of count()

Tags: parse-platform

Anyone who's read Parse documentation has stumbled upon [this](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-counting-objects)

> Caveat: Count queries are rate limited to a maximum of 160 requests per minute. They can also return inaccurate results for classes with more than 1,000 objects. Thus, it is preferable to architect your application to avoid this sort of count operation (by using counters, for example.)

Why's there such limitation and inaccuracy?

Answer (score 2):

To quote the Parse Engineering Blog Post: [Building Scalable Apps on Parse](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/building-scalable-apps-on-parse/)

> Suppose you are building a product catalog. You might want to display
>   the count of products in each category on the top-level navigation
>   screen. If you run a count query for each of these UI elements, they
>   will not run efficiently on large data sets because MongoDB does not
>   use counting B-trees. Instead, we recommend that you use a separate
>   Parse Object to keep track of counts for each category. Whenever a
>   product gets added or deleted, you can increment or decrement the
>   counts in an afterSave or afterDelete Cloud Code handler.

To add on to this, here is another quote by Hector Ramos from [the Parse Developers Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/1GOv37oTY2k)

> Count queries have always been expensive once you throw some
>   constraints in. If you only care about the total size of the
>   collection, you can run a count query without any constraints and that
>   one should be pretty fast, as getting the total number of records is a
>   different problem than counting how many of these match an arbitrary
>   list of constraints. This is just the reality of working with database
>   systems.

The inaccuracy is ***not*** due to the 1000 request object limit. The count query will try to get the total number of records regardless of size, but since the operation may take a large amount of time to complete, it is possible that the database has changed during that window and the count value that is returned may no longer be valid.

The recommended way to handle counts is to essentially maintain your own index using before/after save hooks. However, this is also a non-ideal solution because save hooks can arbitrarily fail part way through and (worse) postSave hooks have no error propagation.

Answer (score 1):

The limitation is simply to stop people using counts too much, they're just as runtime costly as full queries in effect.

The inaccuracy is because queries are limited to 1000 result objects (100 by default) and counts have the same hard limit.

You can run a recursive query to build up a count, but it's a crappy option. Hence the only really good option at this point in time (and as far as we can see in the future) is to keep an index of the things you're interested in counting and update the counts when anything changes. You would usually do that with save hooks in cloud code.